# Python else condition prints several times

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements, xlrd

Here I wrote the following code to search for headers from an excel sheet, it can search for the headers, but for each successful iteration, it prints success separately and also same for the error.

```
    for i in sheet_data:
        if (i[0] == "BN") and (i[1] == "YOU"):      
            found_list.append(i)
            print("Success")
        else:
            print("error")
```

>

```
error
error
error
Success
error
Success
error
error
```

If the iteration found the string at once or twice then print success only once hence it will not print error. If there is no success iteration then only it has to print error (else) once. (I just need to print success or error)

Comment: Difficult to predict without knowing your input

Comment: Can you show `sheet_data` variable?

Comment: okay, I wil post

Comment: If you want to print only once, then don't do it in the loop. Once you know what you must know, set or clear a boolean, leave the loop and print.

Comment: Please read my question correctly instead of devote for my question.Now i got the answer and i accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always printing something when you are testing, use a temporary variable and print the result after scanning the full list:

```
success = False
for i in sheet_data:
    if (i[0] == "BN") and (i[1] == "YOU"):      
        found_list.append(i)
        success = True
if success:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("error")
```